# Operator error ?? for instances of two classes

Tags: c#

Both instances are instances of a class. What is the problem?
Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'A' and 'B'.

```
A myA = new A(); 
B myB = new B(); 

object? Ok1 = myA ?? myA; //Ok
object? Ok2 = myB ?? myB; //Ok

object? Error = myA ?? myB; //Error. Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'A' and 'B'

class A
{

}

class B
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler can't work out the "best type" to use for the expression. (It tries for *either* `A` *or* `B`, but doesn't look for common types in the hierarchy.)

From the [ECMA standard, section 12.15](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/expressions.md#1215-the-null-coalescing-operator):

> The type of the expression `a ?? b` depends on which implicit conversions are available on the operands. In order of preference, the type of `a ?? b` is `A₀`, `A`, or `B`, where `A` is the type of a (provided that a has a type), B is the type of b(provided that b has a type), and `A₀` is the underlying type of `A` if `A` is a nullable value type, or `A` otherwise.

If you cast either of the operands to `object?`, it should be fine:

```cs
object? success = myA ?? (object?) myB;
```

Comment: You could also define an implicit operator from A to B (and vice versa) and wouldn't need the cast and the ?? operator would then work.

Comment: @B.O.B.: True, although I'd say that's pretty *rarely* a good idea.

Comment: Yeah. I was just throwing it out there. I don't know what the project requirements are, but it also seems like a bad idea to store a completely different type of object in the variable based on whether the first object is null or not. Seems like some hinkiness going on.